# How can we display the sum of values in bot framework composer using properties?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I have created a chatbot using bot composer, this bot is developed to ask few multiple-choice questions and for each answer given by the user, some score is assigned. I am using properties to store each score for each answer. After all the questions answered by the user, the bot should show the total score.
when I do the below operation.
user.total_score = ${user.point1} + ${user.point2}[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9rhS.png)

when we send the response as Your score is ${user.total_score}
it is displaying individual values of each point. i.e Your score is 4 + 5

can someone help me in displaying the total score?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU5Zg.png)

Comment: Can you share some code, please? From your description, it is not clear what you are struggled with

Comment: I am using bot framework composer not the code

Comment: Hard to tell without more info but it looks like your property's value is a string. If so, could you try and change it to a number

Comment: if we select property value as number then we should give direct value. we are not allowed to give as ${user.point1}+${user.point2}